# How to use 100% of the current window height (no more, no less)?

Tags: html, css, scroll, height

I am developing a web app that is supposed to have the feeling of a desktop app. I want my layout to make use of the entire browser window height (no more, no less). I've made an image that show the intended structure of the page.

[Intended layout](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/layoutu.jpg/)

In other words, I don't want the user to be able to scroll the entire page, but rather the different sections of the page. Similar to how most desktop applications work.

I've read everything about how to create columns with equal height etc., but non of the solutions I've found adds scrolling to the different sections instead of the entire page, and still makes use of the entire window height.

I hope someone has a solution to this, it would be awesome. I've been googling for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you 90% of the way there:

http://jsfiddle.net/aEdc7/

However, have you considered using a JavaScript framework such as [Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com/)? Take a look at some of the demos: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

#container > div {
    position: absolute
}
#header {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: cyan;
    height: 40px
}
#nav {
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow-y: auto
}
#content {
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 150px;
    right: 0;
    background: #eee;
    overflow-y: auto
}
#error {
    top: 40px;
    left: 150px;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background: #444
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="nav"><br /></div>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That piece of HTML/CSS worked like a charm, thanks a lot! Exactly what I needed. I haven't considered a JavaScript framework yet, I would prefer to keep it as lightweight as possible. Would you say there are any drawbacks of sticking to HTML/CSS instead of Ext JS for instance?

Comment: @Christofer Eliasson: I don't know exactly what you're making, but you said `"the feeling of a desktop app"`, which instantly makes me think that you should at least check out Ext JS, because it can do some very cool "desktop-style" things: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/layout/complex.html - however, that might just be overcomplicating it.

Comment: I agree with you, that is an awesome example, and something very close to what I've been looking for. I will take a closer look at Ext JS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with jQuery, please see http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm .

They are also more plug ins like this out there.

Comment: This is a GREAT solution...very easy and tons of features!

Answer (score 0):

There's a CSS trick that can be usefull in your case :
declare an element's position as absolute
set the top position at 0
set the bottom position at 0
The height of the element should not be defined, or defined to auto.

Than the element is full height of its parent.

this can probably help to build the layout you're looking for.

example code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
            }

            .header {
                height: 40px;
                background: #aabbff;
            }

            .contentLeft {
                position: absolute;
                top: 40px;
                bottom: 20px;
                left: 0;
                width: 40%;
                overflow: auto;
                background: #eeeeff;
            }

            .contentRight {
                position: absolute;
                top: 40px;
                bottom: 20px;
                right: 0;
                width: 60%;
                overflow: auto;
                background: #ddddff;
            }

            .bottom {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                border: 3px solid blue;
                height: 14px;
                background: #9999ff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="contentLeft"></div>
            <div class="contentRight"></div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ciao,

Nico